# RichTextBox with variable number of bound runs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I was working on a project recently where I feel a nice solution would be to display a paragraph in a `RichTextBox` that is bound to a collection of objects that will hold a string and a few properties about that string.  I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
<RichTextBox Name="rtb" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Courier New">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding foo}"/>
            <Run Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding bar}"/>
            <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding baz}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

This works fine, however this is defining all the bindings ahead of time, but I actually won't know them until run time, each string will be stored into a collection.  I was trying to think of a way to define and bind multiple `Run` blocks and place them all in the `RichTextBox` to be displayed.  I would prefer a primarily xaml solution if possible, but if I must do it in the code behind that may be OK as well as long as the bindings stick and everything updates properly after the initial load.

I tried something like this, but was having trouble figuring how how to bind to the `Text` property of a `Run` from the code behind:

```
foreach (var item in col)
{        
    Run run = new Run();
    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Source = this;
    b.Path = new PropertyPath(item.StaticText);
    run.SetBinding(run.Text, b);    //Tells me Text is not a dependency property
                                    //But it could be bound if this were xaml?
}
```

I also tried putting an `ItemsControl` inside the `RichTextBox` that had `Run` as the data template of the items, but it wouldn't allow me to make the data template a `Run` tag, and I'm not sure that would have worked anywway.

Any guidance on the best approach, or what's wrong with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have gotten the job done for me, I created an `ItemsControl` that used a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`.  Then I can bind each item to my collection of strings and it comes out looking like a nice paragraph of variable strings.  I'll keep the question open though in case someone comes up with a more elegant solution.

```
<RichTextBox Name="rtb" IsReadOnly="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StaticText,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/><TextBlock Text=" "/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this...

```
<Paragraph>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyRuns}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Foreground="{Binding Color}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--<Run Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding foo}"/>
    <Run Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding bar}"/>
    <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding baz}"/>-->
</Paragraph>
```

And define `MyRuns` as a collection on your view model, e.g.

```
public ObservableCollection<RunData> MyRuns { get; set; }
```

Put properties in your `RunData` etc.

And you can of course remove `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`, that's just for fun